# Boot loop crucial mx 300 and windows

Tags: ssd

just bought crucial mx 300 ssd and connected it with sata to usb 2 adapter, using dell laptop win 8.1, installed the crucial software.

Wanted to "sanitize" drive before cloning windows on it.
In addition i should note that i have not yet updated the drivers of the ssd.

I am stuck in a boot loop now when it boots and loads the micron program and asks for usage? Or is usage optional? **Screen shot added**

I tried disconnecting the ssd completely after force shutdown and it still will not load windows, instead it shows this screen.

UPDATE: now something similar happened when i tried to update the firmware. there are 3 options to update firmware with crucial.
1 update with their program and in a reboot it updates the firmware.
2 update with the program with no reboot.
3 update with flashable cd\disk on key.
in all 3 options the update failed and in the 2 that involve booting, the laptop was stuck in boot loop.

**essentially i can not update the SSDs firmware or flash it (sanitize) to factory clean condition.**
[image: pic of screen]

Comment: If you disconnect the drive and connect it while the is is running what happens?

Comment: I tried to disconnect completely and boot windows and it keeps loading the micron program even when the drive is disconnected.

Comment: Do you have some other device connected that the machine is booting from? If so, disconnect it.

Comment: now some thing similar happened when i tried to update the firmware. there are 3 options to update firmware with crucial. 1 update with their program and in a reboot it updates the firmware. 2 update with the program with no reboot and 3 update with flashable cd\disk on key. in all 3 options the update failed and in the 2 that involve booting the laptop was stuck in boot loop.